# Javascript/Typescript: Use a variable like const { var as othername } = ...?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to do this:

```js
const { colors as ThemeColors } = useTheme();
```

but I can't... and I don't want do this:

```js
const { colors } = useTheme();
const ThemeColors = colors;
```

Do you know a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to create an alias (I don't know why it is called an alias, because for me alias is copied by reference):

```
const { colors: ThemeColors } = useTheme();
```

However, this is not copied by reference but as value. That means changing `ThemeColors` will not change `colors`.

Comment: Where is it called an alias?

Comment: I think nowhere right? xD But I hear a lot of people calling it `aliasing` or `alias`.